# Virtual memory issue with QtCreator

Tags: qt, memory-leaks, qt-creator, qt5, virtual-memory

Recently I opened a fairly large project in QtCreator, and on running it, I got and error saying "virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory" and it terminated. (Unfortunately I dint save that message and havent been able to reproduce it again.)

I reinstalled QtCreator as was suggested on some QtForums regarding this issue.

Now, when I run this project, my machine starts slowing down slowly before it just freezes completely.

Anything I can try doing to avoid such issue ?

Ubuntu 13.04

Qt 5.2.0

RAM : 3 GB

Swap Space : 2 GB

Project: https://github.com/bdoin/GCompris

Comment: The only thing you can do is to debug creator itself and find where it leaks memory. Hopefully the memory leak is there no matter the project size, so you'd fire it up under valgrind, open a small project, and go from there.

Comment: How does it behave on other computers?

Comment: And if you run that project from command line it works perfectly?

Comment: @user3427419 Nops, same issue from command line as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same problem:

1. One similar question was asked here : [cc1plus: Virtual memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577816/cc1plus-virtual-memory-exhausted)

This dint work fine for me though.

2. Some people (on other forums) suggested re installing QtCreator, which dint help either.
3. Finally someone suggested (on other forums) to reinstall the build-essential package and it worked for me.

To make it clear, I realized ther was a process 'cc1plus' which was just taking memory continuously. After re installation also it takes lot of memory, but not enough to cause errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed now in GCompris. It was creating huge qrc files (Qt resource files). Now each activity in GCompris has its own qrc and they are loaded dynamically at runtime instead of being statically integrated in the binary. This process was using a lot of memory.